# Download files from Flutter webview

Tags: flutter, webview

I'm using the [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter/versions/4.0.7) (4.0.7) package to open webViews in my app.

I want to download a file (PDF, Excel) from my webView to my device. But I'm getting:

> Document cloned, element located at -100000,0 with size 900x715.6190795898438 using computed rendering"

How do I achieve this using that specific package?

### Update

After some investigation, I added a breakpoint to my `onNavigationRequest`, to detect the URL when downloading the file. I noticed that I'm getting a blob URL:

> blob:https://example.company_name.com/d67da043-159f-43d8-b9c9-82b1da1e2b30

And After it, I was redirected to the following page:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use URL Launcher plugin to sort downloadable file extenstion to launch in browser,
you can try something like (if url ends with .pdf or .docx etc)

Comment: Please share an example

Comment: this is example to trigger launch url plugin, make conditions like url.endswith (pdf) then return _launchurl


void main() => runApp(
      const MaterialApp(
        home: Material(
          child: Center(
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _launchUrl,
              child: Text('Show Flutter homepage'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

Future<void> _launchUrl() async {
  if (!await launchUrl(_url)) {
    throw Exception('Could not launch $_url');
  }
}